# AppSettings.*.json files not copied on Publish in ASP.NET CORE 1.1

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core-1.1

I am publishing an ASP.NET Core 1.1 project with **.csproj** file ...

When I publish it the project is compiled and all the files, including the ones in wwwroot are copied, but all appsettings.*.json files are missing.

I am not sure why because I have the following:

```
<Content Include="**\*.json" />
```

What am I missing? Here is the complete .csproj file.

```
<Project>

  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" />

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>
    <PreserveCompilationContext>true</PreserveCompilationContext>
    <PackageTargetFallback>$(PackageTargetFallback);portable-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81;</PackageTargetFallback>      
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="**\*.cs" />   
    <Content Include="**\*.json" />
    <EmbeddedResource Include="**\*.resx" />        
  </ItemGroup>

 <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="System.Runtime" Version="4.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NETCore.App" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web" Version="1.0.0-alpha-20161104-2-112">
      <PrivateAssets>All</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools" Version="1.1.0-preview4-final" />  
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCaching" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCompression" Version="1.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Rewrite" Version="1.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="1.1.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools" Version="1.0.0-msbuild1-final" /> 
  </ItemGroup>  

  <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />

  <Target Name="Prepublish" BeforeTargets="PrepareForPublish" Condition=" '$(IsCrossTargetingBuild)' != 'true' ">
    <Exec Command="npm install" />
    <Exec Command="bower install" /> 
    <Exec Command="gulp build" />
  </Target>   

</Project>
```

Comment: Any news? I am facing the same problem.

Comment: I'm also interested in the solution to this

Comment: I faced with the same problem. Just change **Copy to Output Directory** to **Copy Always**.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with four json files I was using as translation files for angular-translate. What I did to include them was explicitly mark them as content.

```
<Content Include="Language\locale-en.json" />
<Content Include="Language\locale-fr.json" />
<Content Include="Language\locale-es.json" />
<Content Include="Language\locale-pt.json" />
```